# dom href not working in edge and internet exploer browsers

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag which is having href defined. But based on browser langauge i am altering the href by using a javascript fucntion. It is working in all browsers except microsoft edge and internet explorer. In edge and explorer it is redirected to the URL mentioned in href. It is not redirecting it to URL based on language mentioned in javascript

```
 <li><a id="fa1" href="https://www.google.com" onclick="openlink()" target="_blank">{!$Label.FooterContactsTab}</a></li>
    function openlink()
      {
        var ulang=navigator.language;
       // if(ulang=="es-ES"){
        if(ulang.indexOf("es") > -1){
        document.getElementById("fa1").href = 
       "www.youtube.com";
        }
        else if (ulang.indexOf("en") > -1){

          document.getElementById("fa1").href = "www.gmail.com";

        }
        //else if(ulang=="zh-CN" || ulang=="zh"){
        else if(ulang.indexOf("zh")> -1){

          document.getElementById("fa1").href = "www.w3schools.com";

        }
        //else if(ulang=="ja-JP"){
        else if(ulang.indexOf("ja") > -1){
          document.getElementById("fa1").href = "www.salesforce.com";

        }
      }
```

Comment: [Try `document.getElementById("fa1").setAttribute('href', 'https://www.cisco.com/cisco/web/siteassets/contacts/index.html? 
        locale=es_ES')`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)